# flask_restplus is not generating the proper Swagger UI

Tags: python, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

Ok I have a project in the following structure in PyCharm:

[image]

The contents of `test_ns.py` is as follows:

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from flask_restplus import Resource
from flask_restplus import reqparse

api = Api(version='1.0', title='My Blog API',
          description='A simple demonstration of a Flask RestPlus powered API')

ns = api.namespace('blog/posts', description='Operations related to blog posts')

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('Hello', required=True, location='form')


@ns.route('/')
class PostsCollection(Resource):

    @api.expect(parser)
    def get(self):
        """
        Returns list of blog posts.
        """

        return "Hello World from Swagger"
```

The content of `server.py` is as follows:

```
from web.test_ns import ns, api
from flask import Flask, Blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)


def configure_app(flask_app):
    flask_app.config['SWAGGER_UI_DOC_EXPANSION'] = 'List'
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_VALIDATE'] = True
    flask_app.config['RESTPLUS_MASK_SWAGGER'] = False


def initialize_app(flask_app):
    configure_app(flask_app)

    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(ns)

    flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)


def main():
    initialize_app(app)
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5000")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I am not getting the appropriate Swagger UI. When I run server.py and access it in my browser this is what I get:

[image]

Its basically not the actual Swagger-UI that I want.

What I want is what is advertised on the [flask_restplus site](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#swagger-ui):

[image]

I just cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

I have gone through a project on GitHub [over here](https://github.com/postrational/rest_api_demo) but I can't understand what I am doing differently or incorrectly. The project uses the same packages for Swagger as me yet I am unable to get the correct output. Where am I going wrong?

The instructions to run the GitHub project can be found [here](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2016/06/19/building-beautiful-restful-apis-using-flask-swagger-ui-flask-restplus/).

The only difference between my project and the GitHub one is the later is just using more modules.

Looking at the server log of Flask I can see that the GitHub project is making a lot more calls to the backend to generate the UI:

[image]

While for me I only make a small number of calls to generate my incorrect Swagger UI:

```
* Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2019 23:37:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2019 23:37:04] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2019 23:37:04] "GET /swaggerui/favicon-16x16.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Feb/2019 23:37:04] "GET /api/swagger.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**What is the reason for the difference?**

I have searched the docs, but I can't find anything. What am I missing?

Even using an example from the [flask_restplus site](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#swagger-ui) fails to give the correct Swagger UI, as advertised.

**What is so magical about the GitHub project why is it the only project that works? What is it doing correctly, that I clearly am not.**

Comment: Try clicking on the "GET". It should expand. What you are getting is the new UI and it is what it is. Looks like docs have an issue.

Comment: @Bhartiya This is the new UI? It sucks. How can I get the UI I want?

Comment: I found this on the github. I don't think changing the API look and feel is possible. https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/407

Answer (score 2):

Both images are Swagger UI, just different versions of it.

- The 1st image (what you get) in Swagger UI v. 3, which is the current version of UI. You can see it in the official Swagger UI demo at https://pestore.swagger.io.
- The 2nd image (from flask_restplus's docs) is Swagger UI v 2, an old version that is no longer developed/supported.

flask_restplus works as expected by keeping its dependencies (including Swagger UI) up-to-date. The issue is with flask_restplus's *documentation*, in that it contains an outdated screenshot of Swagger UI that is different from what the users actually get. Consider filing a documentation update request with the flask_restplus project.